# Avoiding double calculation of the common points in two different buffer zones in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, buffer, intersection

I have a **point Shapefile of 100 Libraries** and a **population count point feature** (have population count to their corresponding points)  of the Toronto neighborhoods. I need to know the number of population points that are **within 1000 m buffer** of the Libraries and need to the number of population within 1000m buffer of the **100 libraries separately**. I have run the buffer tool for the library points. But there are some overlapping buffers. No that I used the **"Tabulate intersection"** tool to count the population points for the 100 library buffer, as expected its counting the population points of the common/overlapping buffer zones for the library buffers. Say "A" and "B" are two buffers having a portion of **common area**. Let's say there are total **2500 population** counts in these **two buffers and 500 of them are in the common Zone**. When I run the Tabulate Intersection tool I get results like for A zone there are 1800 points and for B zone 1700 points. I know this is calculating all the population points that lies within 1000m of both the Buffers - A and B.

Now I want to avoid this extra calculation and want to know the points counts for A and B separately that will have aggregate of 2500 points.
Can anyone please help me on this?
[image]

Comment: Try near tool between points and libraries. Exclude points outside distance limit.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you are asking, if you want the count of just A and just B and the count of the overlap of A & B then try union your buffers, and then do a spatial join with that dataset?